# performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

inside of `componentWillReceiveProps` function I called another function:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

  if(nextProps.cart){
    var cart = nextProps.cart;
    this.setState({cart:cart,
      offCart:cartHelper.getOffCart(cart),
      totalPay:cartHelper.getTotalPayCart(cart)});

      this.useFinance()//at this line makes this error

  }

  useFinance(){

    if(this.state.useFinance)
    {
      this.setState({useFinance:false})
    }else{
      if(this.state.totalPay > this.state.user.user.finance)
      {
        this.setState({useFinance:false})
      }else{
        this.setState({useFinance:true})
      }
    }

  }
```

I'm using `react-redux` and I should call `useFinance` function When the cart is updated.

I got this error message:

```
warning.js?8a56:33 Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 2, pending 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Do not call setState every time in `componentWillReceiveProps` if value is still same. Check value which receives from `nextprops` and actual value inside the `state` if they are not equal then call `setState`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if (nextProps.cart && nextProps.cart != this.props.cart) { //Do this in case of object => JSON.stringify(nextProps.cart) != JSON.stringify(this.props.cart)
        var cart = nextProps.cart;
        this.setState({
            cart: cart,
            offCart: cartHelper.getOffCart(cart),
            totalPay: cartHelper.getTotalPayCart(cart)
        });
        this.useFinance() //at this line makes this error

    }
}

useFinance() {

    if (this.state.useFinance) {
        this.setState({
            useFinance: false
        })
    } else {
        if (!(this.state.totalPay > this.state.user.user.finance)) {
            this.setState({
                useFinance: true
            })
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Updated check now.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to perform single `setState` update like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

  if(nextProps.cart){
    var cart = nextProps.cart;

    const useFinance = !this.state.useFinance || (this.state.totalPay <= this.state.user.user.finance)
    this.setState({
      useFinance,
      cart: cart,
      offCart: cartHelper.getOffCart(cart),
      totalPay: cartHelper.getTotalPayCart(cart)
    });
  }
}
```

However, this may end up in an infinite update as you

> update state -> componentWillRecieveProps -> update state ->
>   componentWillReceiveProps ...

That's why you need to check if an update is necessary:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

  if(this.doWeNeedAnUpdate(this.props, nextProps)){
    ...
  }
}
```